# Is it possible to link a control to multiple gestures in iOS?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

The question I have is if it is possible to create a control, similar to a UIButton, but can have the tap and the long press gesture linked together? The reason I ask is because I would like to mimic the functionality of the application in the home screen (tap to open application, hold to move it around or delete it). I would like to create a button, or use the UIButton if the functionality is possible, that can either perform a simple calculation when pressed, but if the button is held down then a view would popup where the user can change the result will be output.

Any advice is greatly appreciated in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correct you need to add several gesture recognizers to UIButton?

Remembering that UIButton is inherited from UIView you can add many gestures to it using:

```
- (void)addGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
```

All gestures will be stored in:

```
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSArray *gestureRecognizers
```

So you can add UILongPressGestureRecognizer as well as other types of gestures.

But to able to make difference between single tap and long press tap - add standard target to UIButton with control event: `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`

Comment: So in that case I don't need a tap gesture? I just want to be sure because I thought that just adding the target to UIControlEventTouchUpInside would also allow it to fire after the long press gesture would fire.

Comment: Yes, you do not need single tap gesture because it will be invoked when you tap down inside but not touch up inside (though in this case you can filter touches using UITouchPhase). So it is up to you.